# Why am I not able to search questions tagged "c" without using square brackets?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, search

I need to search the questions tagged "c". So I searched with "c" in the search box without using square brackets. I didn't get any results, and I was redirected to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c). From Stack Overflow search options, "**any search terms matching the most popular 60 tags will be automatically mapped to a tag to help narrow your search**" ("c" is in top 60). I used to search with `ios`, `osx`, `iphone`. All are correctly mapping to their respective tag, but "c" doesn't. It is a bug or did I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Searching for c](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c) will now redirect to the tag page, other single character searches are now supported as well.